# Ordenar un JSON alfabéticamente

Tags: javascript, json, ordenamiento

Estoy intentando ordenar un JSON por un campo de manera alfabetica pero no logro tener exito.

El codigo de la funcion que estuve probando este, pero al final no me ordena el JSON :

```js
   const ordenar = function () {

        let array = [
            {Materia: 'DERECHO CONSTITUCIONAL', SubMateria: 'ACCION DE AMPARO'},
            {Materia: 'COMERCIAL', SubMateria: 'OBLIGACION DE DAR SUMA DE DINERO'},
            {Materia: 'CONTENCIOSO ADMINISTRATIVO', SubMateria: 'REVISION JUDICIAL'},
            {Materia: 'FAMILIA TUTELAR', SubMateria: 'VIOLENCIA CONTRA LAS MUJERES'},
            {Materia: 'CIVIL', SubMateria: 'OBLIGACION DE DAR SUMA DE DINERO'},
            {Materia: 'FAMILIA CIVIL', SubMateria: 'DIVORCIO POR CAUSAL'},
            {Materia: 'LABORAL', SubMateria: 'NULIDAD DE RESOLUCION ADMINISTRATIVA'},
        ]

        console.log("array inicial : ", array)

        var newArray=array.sort((a, b)=> {
            var textA = a.Materia;
            var textB = b.Materia;
            
            return textA - textB;
        });
        console.log("array salida : ", newArray)
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como ordenar un objeto JSON por orden alfabético?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/268862/como-ordenar-un-objeto-json-por-orden-alfab%c3%a9tico)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes utilizar el método Sort haciendo una comparación directa entre los string, ejemplo:

```
const ordenar = function () {

    let array = [
        {Materia: 'DERECHO CONSTITUCIONAL', SubMateria: 'ACCION DE AMPARO'},
        {Materia: 'COMERCIAL', SubMateria: 'OBLIGACION DE DAR SUMA DE DINERO'},
        {Materia: 'CONTENCIOSO ADMINISTRATIVO', SubMateria: 'REVISION JUDICIAL'},
        {Materia: 'FAMILIA TUTELAR', SubMateria: 'VIOLENCIA CONTRA LAS MUJERES'},
        {Materia: 'CIVIL', SubMateria: 'OBLIGACION DE DAR SUMA DE DINERO'},
        {Materia: 'FAMILIA CIVIL', SubMateria: 'DIVORCIO POR CAUSAL'},
        {Materia: 'LABORAL', SubMateria: 'NULIDAD DE RESOLUCION ADMINISTRATIVA'},
    ]

    console.log("array inicial : ", array)
            
    //Filtrado de forma ascendente
    var newArray = array.sort((a,b)=> (a.Materia > b.Materia ? 1 : -1))
    //Filtrado de forma descendente
    var newArray = array.sort((a,b)=> (a.Materia < b.Materia ? 1 : -1))

    console.log("array salida : ", newArray)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Algunas consideraciones:

Lo que quieres ordenar es un array de objetos, no un objeto, ni un json.

`.sort` altera el array que ordena, por lo que no es necesario guardarlo en otra variable.

`.sort` por defecto tiene un comportamiento no deseado con las mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres no ingleses:

```js
let array = [
            {Materia: 'á'},
            {Materia: 'e'},
            {Materia: 'É'},
            {Materia: 'A'},
            {Materia: 'AB'},
            {Materia: 'ZZ'},
            {Materia: 'Ñ'},
            {Materia: 'N'}
        ];

array.sort((a,b)=> (a.Materia > b.Materia ? 1 : -1))


console.log(array)
```

Se puede comprobar que las variantes no solucionan el problema.

Lo que se puede hacer es usar [.localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) utilizando el segundo parámetro que son los locales, en el caso de español es 'es'. Ademas se puede indicar que solo consideremos la base,  la base de "á" es igual a "a" y a "A". Ejemplo:

```js
let array = [
            {Materia: 'á'},
            {Materia: 'e'},
            {Materia: 'É'},
            {Materia: 'A'},
            {Materia: 'AB'},
            {Materia: 'ZZ'},
            {Materia: 'Ñ'},
            {Materia: 'N'}
        ];

array.sort((a, b) => a.Materia.localeCompare(b.Materia, 'es', {sensitivity: 'base'}))


console.log(array)
```